# Can't import local json file in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to import a local file to use the data in it. 
I have tried the require method and the import method. Neither seems to work.
I'm using Angular 5 and Typescript 2.9.2. I am locked to angular 5.
I'm building for aot and when I look at the fesm5 file that gets exported the json file does not seem to resolve.
(I DO NOT WANT TO PULL IT IN WITH HTTP...)

```
import * as data from '../../assets/file.json';
```

When I try to set tsconfig value to:

```
 "resolveJsonModule": true,
```

I get an error on build:

```
 Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
at addReferencesToSourceFile (/Users/ME/Projects/PROJECT/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/compiler_host.js:520:54)
at TsCompilerAotCompilerTypeCheckHostAdapter.getSourceFile (/Users/ME/Projects/PROJECT/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/compiler_host.js:348:13)
```

I have also tried the:

```
declare module '*.json' {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

This doesn't seem to help at all.

Also tried:

```
declare function require(url: string);

var data = require('../../assets/file.json');
```

This does not seem to resolve the json in the final file either.

Comment: @dota2pro Yes, the problem is the compiled js file for aot does not have the import/require resolved... The build will complete but when I load the aot file i get that its not resolved: ERROR in ./dist/PROJECT/fesm5/LIBRARY.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../assets/file.json' in '/Users/ME/Projects/PROJECT/dist/LIBRARY/fesm5'

Answer (score 0):

You can put your file under **assets** folder and get it using HTTP GET from HttpClient module, this will return the whole json file, use your file path in your GET request URL; something like this:

```js
this.http.get('../assets/file.json')
    .subscribe(jsonFormat => { 
      //Your code 
});
```

Comment: This happens in the component. I'm looking to import outside of the component....

Comment: You can use wherever you want, it will be via injectable service, you need to adjust your service to return Observable, and subscribe on it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service for all the GET, POST, PUT& DELETE implementations. Then in your GET method of HttpClient that is imported from ‘@angular/common/http’, call the JSON with the link to your local JSON file.

```
    public getAbout(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get("./assets/json/about.json");
    }
```